# Executing python from a shortcut breaks its imports

Tags: python, package, shortcut, python-packaging

I have a project where I have made some packages of my own. The project folder looks like this

```
Project
   - my_package
      __init__.py
      file1.py
      file2.py
   main.py
```

The main.py file has the line `import my_package`

The **init**.py file in my_package has these lines:

```py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "my_package/")
from file1 import *
from file2 import *
```

If I cd to the main.py folder and run it, it works fine, but if I create a shortcut in my desktop and try to launch it, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "/home/kolterdyx/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "my_package/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'file1'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "/home/kolterdyx/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "my_package/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'file2'
```

This is my shortcut/launcher:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=0.0.1
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/home/kolterdyx/VoidShips/Launcher  #Launcher is a python script compiled with PyInstaller
Name=VoidShips
```

I guess this is because it tries to find `file1.py` and `file2.py` in the desktop and since they aren't it looks for python modules, and it does not find them.

How can I use a shortcut and still make the program run from its own directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use relative imports:

```py
from .file1 import *
from .file2 import *
```

You can refer for example to [this](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/) article for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the PyInstaller launcher you created works. However if it works for you when cd to the main.py folder you could just create a simple bash script and run the bash script using the shortcut.

Example: youlauncher.sh

```sh
cd /path/to/folder/of/mainpy
python main.py
```

Also i would recommend using relative imports (`from . import file1, file2`)